# Production deployment of mean.js application

Tags: gruntjs, production-environment, meanjs, pm2, mean.io

In production site I can see individual js files rather than the concatenated file application JavaScript and CSS files. First I run the command grunt build and the output is

```
$ grunt build

Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Running "less:dist" (less) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 272 files lint free.

Running "ngAnnotate:production" (ngAnnotate) task
>> 1 file successfully generated.

Running "uglify:production" (uglify) task
>> 1 file created.

Running "cssmin:combine" (cssmin) task
>> 1 file created. 193.41 kB → 144.31 kB

Done, without errors.
```

This command create 3 files in dist folder and I also removed public/dist folder from .gitignore. My **public** folder contains **dist** folder but after restarting production with pm2, results are still same. It is not loading files from dist folder

```
pm2 restart 0 --env production
[My MeanJS App][1]
```

Comment: Do you get a blank page on the browser when you run it in production mode ?

Comment: Yeah but it is resolved now. I am getting an exception on server that is why it is giving me 502 nginx error

Comment: Check your `config/assets/production.js` file to see if you specify all your assets.